# Лицензия на BitLocker

Tags: windows-7, лицензирование

Есть ли лицензионное ограничение на использование BitLocker в разных версиях Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

Да, такое ограничение есть. BitLocker включается в поставку старших версий Windows. Как легко видно из [сравнения версий](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-RU/windows7/products/compare?T1=tab01), только Windows 7 Максимальная поддерживает BitLocker.

Comment: Может неправильно сформулировал. Я хочу сделать так. Шифровать с помощью Максимальной версии, а использовать на младших дешевых версиях. Получается бесплатно и удобно, плюс поддержка проводника. Есть ли здесь подвох?

Comment: А разве это будет работать? По сути у вас есть некий раздел, который вы защищаете. Если вы тот же самый раздел перенесете на другую машину, то там при отсутствии поддержки BitLocker он просто не должен быть доступен.

Comment: Дело в том, что я так использую как описал. Меня сейчас волнует только лицензионное ограничение на такой способ использование этой фичи.